# How to avoid tag inputs getting width of 100%

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

So this is a 2 part question specifically for the Angular input tags project.

I am currently using it and the inputs that it creates get set to width 100% on the input tag itself. Because it is on the element itself it overrides any other styling I use (except !important or js). Short of forking the project is there any way to turn this off?

Part two is can I remove the input portion once the max-tag amount is reached? it seems counter intuitive to still be able to type after the max is reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Part 1

You can change the default width by using a custom CSS class:

**HTML**

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" class="myclass"></tags-input>
```

**CSS**

```
.myclass .host {
  width: 50%;
}
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DIRsqB3ufrWp6LcJpKEY?p=preview)

### Part 2

You can hide the input by using a custom CSS class as well:

**HTML**

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" ng-class="{'hide-input': tags.length > 3}"></tags-input>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide-input .input {
  display: none;
}
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cekHskF0SmbNzZNAtGlA?p=preview).

Keep in mind that the user won't be able to use the keyboard to remove tags, though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually setting `display:block` along with the width seems to work as well

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue regarding the width of the `ng-tags-input` due to another CSS file `ace.css`, Width of the component weren't appearing as expected due the Width value coming form `ace.css`.

To solve it I just created another CSS file to override width value coming form `ace.css`, added it after `ace.css`, its working now.

**CSS**

```
.tags {
    width: 80%;
}
```